# Problem with polling sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, fork, polling

After I begin the polling loop, all messages printed after the first iteration require me to press enter in the terminal for it to be displayed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket, select, os, pty, sys

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 5007))
s.listen(5)

mypoll = select.poll()
mypoll.register(s.fileno() )

while True:
    print "poll time"
    subr = mypoll.poll()
    for x in subr[0]:

        if x == s.fileno():
            conn, addr = s.accept()

            pid, fd = pty.fork()
            if pid != 0:
                mypoll.register(fd)
                print "done. go back to poll now"
            else:
                print "forked"
                #handles new connection

        else:
            data = os.read(x,1024)
            print data
```

Comment: This program probably have the hardst to follow flow I've seen in many many months now. You should fix up the basic errors here. You're forking of a child that will resume accepting connections concurrently with the parent - sounds bad. You're regisring the controlling terminal of the child with the poll loop, but not the accepted connection ?

Comment: i forgot to put the infinite loop where it should be handling the new fork. I wish i could edit it so i can replace the

"#handles new connection"
with a:

while True:
    pass

Answer (score 1):

After the first iteration, haven't you registered the pty fd, and are then polling it? And its fd will never be equal to the socket fd, so you will then os.read the pty fd. And isn't that now reading from your terminal? And so won't typing a return cause it to "print data"?

Comment: All the fd's should be going to the Final else statement, but only after they have data for me to read in.